# How to correctly overload a variable in class inheritance with the same variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I need to override or overload a variable in a class inheritance. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        type(a) = str

class MyClass(MainClass):
   def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
       type(a) = object of one of my classes.
```

How do I achieve this in Python 3? I have looked into inheritance but either this type of situation is not discussed or I don't get it.

Comment: What? That's not even valid syntax! Could you give a less abstract example? As written it's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried or how it's failed. Python is dynamically typed, so you don't necessarily need to introduce a subclass to pass a different kind of thing as `a`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In the first example he casts a variable to string. In the second he recasts it into something else. I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: @Bharel not to me. Are they trying to say that `a` should be a string in the first case and something else in the second? That doesn't strike me as a particularly clear way of conveying that if so (not least because you `can't assign to function call`). And why do they think Python cares either way?

Comment: I think what you are searching for, are the decorators. It's something that can be achieved with it

Comment: @Bharel So you can answer the question? Or rewrite the question to clarify what is actually being asked with your own words/examples? Because I can do neither; this question is not clear at all, I have no idea what OP is trying to do, and the example which has at least 8 errors does not help either…

Comment: Sorry for the bad syntax. I couldn't correct it for some reason. The 'a' variable from the main class is set to a specific type. I want to provide my own type.

Comment: Agree. Need a better example and some examples of how you are going to call this to help illustrate the concern/issue.

Comment: @Godfrey *"set"* by what? Again, Python is *dynamically typed*, `a` doesn't have to be a specific type. Give a [mcve], some *actual code*, or at least a valid demo of how you'd like to interact with it. Also removing the parentheses didn't make a difference, and you didn't add enough colons. Not that it would be syntactically valid even after that.

Comment: If I call `MainClass('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`, then a new `MainClass` object is created with the string `'a'` being the value for the argument `a`. If I call it with `MainClass(123, 'b', 'c', 'd')`, then the value for `a` is the integer `123`. Same applies to the subclass `MyClass`. There really isn’t any special case about inheritance here.

Comment: I was expecting a super().__init__() example to address this situation or maybe something in the methods example.  Either ways, i think i will need to study the class  i am trying to inherit from.

Comment: Write some unit tests to prove what happens in each case.

Comment: @Godfrey A subclass is not required to have the same constructor parameters as the base class. The subclass is also not required to just pass them to the base class the way it gets them. So nothing prevents you from calling `super().__init__()` with a string although you got a completely other value for `a`.

Comment: Except the main class states specifically that 'a' has to be string and not a file-like object. I want to recreate 'a' as  a file-like object. I know i will need to change a few things but i want to get the first part right! Changing the type to my own type (before i can do my own abstraction).

Comment: @Godfrey then give a [mcve] *of that situation*. What you've posted so far is so abstract as to be of no explanatory value whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

What it seems like you're trying to do is make each class able to access the other. However this is not how class inheritance works. Try using this for the classes to access each other.

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c): # main class with variables, a, b and c.
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def printall(self): # this will be so we can see what happens
        print(self.a)
        print(self.b)
        print(self.c)

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, class_inst, a): # another class of a class and a variable
        self.a = a
        self.class_inst = class_inst

    def override(self): # this will override(or overload) the other class variable.
        self.class_inst.a = self.a
```

Write some testing code for it like this.

```
class_inst_one = MainClass("Hello","World","!")
class_inst_two = MyClass(class_inst_one, "Replacement")
class_inst_one.printall()
class_inst_two.override()
class_inst_one.printall()
```

Now you should get an output like this.

```
Hello
World
!
Replacement
World
!
```

Comment: I don't think this is what i want to do yet but i will test it. I want to Inherit  'b' , 'c', 'd' from main class but i want to define my own 'a' in a new class. It is confusing. And no , i am not a python newbie.

Comment: Then you need to be clear what it is you are trying to achieve. All I can establish is that you want to store two different types in a variable, depending on whether you create the base or derived class. Remember that Python is a dynamic language, so that is perfectly legal. You will only fall foul if you start making assumptions about that variable in your code and try to call functions etc on it for one type, when it is in fact the other type. Also, if you find yourself type checking in dynamic code, that is a code smell. Add more code to your examples - inside the classes and calling code.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to *reset* the variable.
Really, it's the same as creating the variable for the first time.

```py
class Base:
    var = 12
class Cls(Base):
    var = 'abc'
```

The class's variables are copied when you create a new class, so these variables **belong** the base, but **gotten** from the the new class. The new class redirects to it's base if this variable is not his.

So, editing the class (*see below*) makes the function reference to it's class, which references to it's base.

```py
class Class(Base):
    def getVar(self):
        return self.var
```

With editing and deleting, it acts on the class instead. The delete removes the reference to the base, and the edit creates delets the old reference and creates its own value.
Notice that editing the base's variables makes the classes variables change to it, but editing the class does not edit the base.
An example is:

```py
class Base:
    a = 10
class Cls(Base): pass

Base.a = 12
# Now Base.a equals Cls.a

Cls.a = 8
# Base.a is still 12, but Cls.a is 8

del Cls.a
# Base.a is still 12, but there is no more of Cls.a
```

To make variables **deep copy** into the class (so edits to the base do *not* affect the class), there is only 1 solution:

```py
class Base:
    var = 12
class Class(Base):
    pass
Class.var = Base.var #add any methods to copy like list.copy()
```

It works because the value from the base is copied through the outside, effectively detaching it from the base and then attaching the value to the class.

Note that a very useful principle is that names with 2 or more underscores (_) and that don't match __{name}__ form are renamed to _{class name}{variable name}. You can use that to separate the variables that have the same name by classes.

By applying functions in the spot I marked for you, you can change the value of the object to anything you want to change it to.

Comment: Good angle. I will try this too. I knew it was either simple or complicated.